# How to get local IPv6 addresses (LSB compliance)

Tags: ipv6, lsb

ioctl does not work with IPv6.

getifaddres - unsupported by LSB

netlink sockets - unsupported by LSB

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you describe your problem more thoroughly and clearly show what you have tried and what output you get when you try it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) It may be after LSB version 4.1:

https://lsbbugs.linuxfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2143

2) Parsing the `/proc/net` tree.

3) Use the POSIX.1-2001 API [getaddrinfo](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/getaddrinfo.3.html) but support is rather limited compared with Win32 which explicitly details the operation to [enumerate interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738520%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: 1. I couldn't find ifaddrs.h in LSB 4.1 core general document.

Comment: 3. It is possible to get addresses using getaddrinfo only?